# pandas style set_table_styles for columns/index does not work with to_excel

Tags: python, css, pandas, pandas-styles

Consider this dummy `DataFrame` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15).reshape(5,3), columns='x y z'.split())

# df
          x         y         z
0  0.725005  0.318429  0.918186
1  0.883890  0.993736  0.795322
2  0.687472  0.328307  0.108520
3  0.608381  0.193478  0.469421
4  0.598708  0.276778  0.433235
```

Assume the below simple pandas styling applied:

```
style = df.style \
    .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('background-color', 'orange')]}]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: 'color: red' if x >.5 else 'color: blue')
```

The `style.render()` seem to confirm the styling has applied for `th` and `td` (snippet below):

```
<style  type="text/css" >
    #T_8b7f1124_a115_11ea_8cf8_48452026764f th {
          background-color: orange;
    }    #T_8b7f1124_a115_11ea_8cf8_48452026764frow0_col0 {
            color:  red;
        }    #T_8b7f1124_a115_11ea_8cf8_48452026764frow0_col1 {
            color:  blue;
        } ...
```

Exporting this as an html displays all the colours as expected.  However when I apply `to_excel`, only the elemental styling is picked up.  The headers/index remains default colours:

```
style.to_excel(r'somefile.xlsx')
```

I tried both `xlsxwriter` and `openpyxl` as engine, both exhibit the same behaviour.

I searched a few questions on `set_table_styles` and `Styler.to_excel`, but all seem to be concerned about the individual elements, didn't seem to address the combination thereof.  Tried searching issue log on github as well, haven't ran into a match so far.

Anybody had luck getting `set_table_styles` and `Styler.to_excel` to work together?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug that still exists in the current version (`1.0.3`).  I have raised a bug in their repo: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34438

Will try to update this when it gets resolved...